# Java Debugger doesn't provide line number of null pointer exception

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception, line-numbers

An application that sends me bugs to a bug tracker when an exception occurs puts out the following obfuscated trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at d.d(APP:1801)
at ew.c(APP:74)
at eu.c(APP:132)
at m.a(APP:189)
at com.GameClient.main(APP:100)
```

After de-obfucating the trace the first line shows me correctly

```
at com.AudioHelper.void tick()(APP:1801)
```

Which in the code is here:

```
public static void tick(){
    if(Window.getID() == GAME_BOARD){
        playAmbientSounds();
    }
    else if(Window.getID() == GAME_MENU){
        playMenuSounds();                     !!!!  THIS IS LINE 1801   !!!
    }
    // Recycle completed Sources in all windows.
    returnCompletedSources();
}
```

Line 1801 is where playMenuSounds(); is called.

My question is, why does the debugger return the line where I call another static method, instead of returning the line where the actual null-pointer exception occured, which I assume has to be inside the static method **playMenuSounds()** (this method is private static) ??

Thanks

Comment: The exception says `tick()` but the method is `update()`... is that method obfuscated or are you in the wrong place?

Comment: Ups... i copied the wrong code. Post Updated.

Comment: Hm, never seen such a case. Maybe the method was inlined and obfuscated in a way the stack frames are no longer visible/reconstructable.

Comment: Could happen if the method was inlined.